# how to use aggreate query using in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following documents in my collection. Need to get all employees in stores using the aggregate function.

//Store 1

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("5b0d3fa6b426ea12ec0f6e5a"),
            "store_name": KFC
            "employees":[
                ObjectId("5b0d4c5ec47e6223a08af5fd"), //query id
                ObjectId("5b3b0ea9074f944699f1bcfc"), 
                ObjectId("5b11558d0a50c067a91875e9"), 
            ],..        },
```

//Store 2

```
{
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b0d3fa6b426ea12ec0f6e5a"),
                "store_name": McDonalds
                "employees":[
                    ObjectId("5b0d4c5ec47e6223a08af5fd"),  
                    ObjectId("5b3b0ea9074f944699f1bcfc"), 
                    ObjectId("5b11558d0a50c067a91875e9"), 
                ],..  },
```

//Store 3

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b0d3fa6b426ea12ec0f6e5a"),
            "store_name": Dominos
            "employees":[
                ObjectId("5b0d4c5ec47e6223a08af5fd"),   
                ObjectId("5b1623905bc92d76abfe0ab1"), 
                ObjectId("5b14e0b1fc1507569f830f7d") 
            ],..   }
```

Using aggregate function

```
    db.getCollection('stores').aggregate([
        {
            $match:{
                "employees":{ 
                    $in:[ ObjectId("5b0d4c5ec47e6223a08af5fd")]  //employee_id
                }
            }
        },{
            $unwind: "$employees"
        },{
            $group: {
                "_id": null,
                "emps": {           
                    $addToSet: "$employees" 
               }
            } 
        }
    ])
```

OUTPUT

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "emps" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b0d4c5ec47e6223a08af5fd"),  // employee id
        ObjectId("5b3b0ea9074f944699f1bcfc"), 
        ObjectId("5b11558d0a50c067a91875e9"), 
        ObjectId("5b1623905bc92d76abfe0ab1"), 
        ObjectId("5b14e0b1fc1507569f830f7d")
    ]
}
```

its fine. I need to get this result without the employee queried id. how i handle it.

Here, How can I remove the queried employee id & need to get result like this

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "emps" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b3b0ea9074f944699f1bcfc"), 
        ObjectId("5b11558d0a50c067a91875e9"), 
        ObjectId("5b1623905bc92d76abfe0ab1"), 
        ObjectId("5b14e0b1fc1507569f830f7d")
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) and repeat your `$in` condition insinde `$not`:

```
db.getCollection('stores').aggregate([
    // your pipeline,
    {
        $addFields: {
            emps: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$emps",
                    as: "emp",
                    cond: { $not: { $in: [ "$$emp", [ ObjectId("5b0d4c5ec47e6223a08af5fd")]  ] } }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) is used to replace existing `emp` field